# WCF Service Host shows 2 instances in Listening ports

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

I have started my WCFServiceHost, when I look into my resource monitor I see this.
[image]
There are two instances of ServiceHost showing , why am I seeing this - when I only started one instance - you will notice the PID is the same . I have searched the internet and also SO ; even reading irrelevant posts - I am using Net.TCP binding - I noticed IPv4, IPv6 (Why both, is that default?, I did not specify v4 or v6 anywhere ; should I concern myself with this or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is that both the IPv4 and IPv6 address resolve to the same MAC address (NIC), and the only thing that is really meaningful is the Port. WCF is just "doing what you want" in case you have a network that has both IPv4 and IPv6. It's nothing to worry about and is just the default behavior.